# Do we need to add indicate the amount for thunder when he was going to tell you the thunder just struck?

Tags: grammar

It was raining heavily.

Suddenly a thunder struck.

My son went to me and said he was scared.

"What's happened?" I said.

> "It's thunder."
>
> "It's a thunder."

Do we need to add indicate the amount for thunder when he was going to tell you the thunder just struck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "a thunder" is never used because "thunder" is only used to mean a plural. You could say "a clap of thunder" or " the noise of thunder" but not just "a thunder".

By the way "what's happened" is grammatical but unnatural sounding. Normally people just say "what happened".